# Algorithm: calculate width of the square rhombus that cover all points

Tags: algorithm, geometry

How to calculate width of the square rhombus that cover all points?
We know only points, and need to find W. There can be any number of points.

Example 1
[image: rhombus that cover all points]

Example 2
[image: rhombus that cover all points]

Comment: Consider about square (not rhombus) version.
Rhombus version is same as it. (only axis rotated 45 deg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotate all point coordinates by Pi/4 (45 degrees) relative to coordinate origin, and find minimum and maximum values for both X and Y coordinates. Maximal difference from `xmax-xmin, ymax-xmin` is square side size.

Answer (score 0):

1. **create 2 basis vectors `u,v` for your rhombus**

   ```
   float c = sqrt(0.5) = 0.70710678118654752440084436210485
   vec2 u = vec2(+c,+c)
   vec2 v = vec2(+c,-c)
   ```
2. **find BBOX using `u,v`**

   ```
   float u0 = min(dot(u,p[i]))
   float u1 = max(dot(u,p[i]))
   float v0 = min(dot(v,p[i]))
   float v1 = max(dot(v,p[i]))
   ```

   where `vec3 p[]` are your points
3. **construct rhombus points**

   ```
   vec2 p0 = u0*u + v0*v
   vec2 p1 = u1*u + v0*v
   vec2 p2 = u1*u + v1*v
   vec2 p3 = u0*u + v1*v
   ```

In case you are not familiar with vector math `dot(a,b)` in 2D is:

```
dot(a,b) = (a.x*b.x) + (a.y*b.y)
```

Comment: Using `1` instead of your `c` will simplify. Scaling only needs to be done once at last.

Comment: Doesn't using `1` avoid the multiplication involved in the dot product? If length of `u` and `v` are `L`, the result value is simply multiplied by `L`.
So, what I need is just divide the result value by `L`.

Comment: @fana aaaah I finaly get your point +1 (you mean remove the `dot` and just use addtion and signs instead  so `dot(u,p)=sign(u.x)p + sign(u.y)p` ) ... :) however brunch these days is slower than multiplication ... you could simply copy sign in case of float but for integers I doubt it can be done brunchlessly